# utc time according to time zone in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem in my application. I display date in this format DD/MM/YYYY example 09/07/2020. But the problem is in my form if the user lives in reunion island enters the date 10/07/2020 (the date of today plus one day), the user lives in France sees 09/07/2020.

How can do in javascript to have the same date enters by the user who lives anywhere.

I want to have this : User lives in Reunion island enters 10/07/2020 and the user lives in France sees 10/07/2020

Answer (score 0):

This is a recurrent issue in JS, and the solution is not easy as `Date` is stored as local time in JS.

You can use an ISO string to input your time: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`.
Executing this:

```
new Date('2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z')
```

Will give the same results.

If you can, i'll advice you to use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), it will you save a lot of effort if you plan to do date operations.

Comment: moment.js will not save you here.  You need momentwithtz to support utc time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save absolute dates i would recommend you to use a library like `moment-timezone` and save the dates in utc.
In order to do this you should do two things:

1. Set the date in utc before sending it to the server:

```
const parseDateBeforeSend = (selectedDate) => {
 const parsedDate = moment(selectedDate).tz('utc', true).startOf('day').toDate()
 return parsedDate
}
```

2. Transform the date to utc before showing it to the user:

```
const showDate = (date) => {
  const parsedDate = moment(date).tz('utc').format("DD/MM/YYYY")
  return parsedDate
}
```

For your information:
When using `tz` function in step 1 you can see that it has a second parameter set to true, what this does is to **keep the original time** and only update the timezone. This would keep the original date you want to show.
In the second step we omit this parameter since we want to show the actual date saved in utc.

Comment: Hello @Bastian E, if i want to have the solution in javascript only without another library, how can i do. Also i want to save aboslutes dates

Comment: Dealing with timezones is not a simple problem, the simplest option is just to save it as string but then you'll lose the ability to query it correctly from a database